# Glyphicon for restore functionality

Tags: glyphicons

I want to add an icon for restore in my code but I can't find anything suitable in the entire glyphicon library. I thought of using the refresh icon because that was the closest match but I am not satisfied with it. Any suggestion guys?

Answer (score 1):

glyphicons-roundabout
glyphicons-refresh
glyphicons-retweet

Try this glyphicons.. if it is not suited then use Fontawesome